# mySQL DBs Synch - development-production

Tags: mysql, synchronization

this is the situation:
I have two server: development server(intranet) and production server(internet).
Authors are inserting data in the production server, on daily basis.
Developers are upgrading the DB structure according to the new web app releases projects.

The problem is: when a new web app is released, I must synchronize the data online with the offline db (updating data). Before upgrading online scripts and db structure.

Is there a better way to perform this merge than a sort of manual/editing/updating via some sql scripts?
Doing it manually is also risk-prone since: sometimes I may lose track of exactly what tables contain newer data and have been updated since the last upgrade...

Note: MySQL replication won't be the solution, since it means it will update data but destroy new structure on development DB.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to view differences and synchronize data between two databases with [Data Comparison](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) tool in dbForge Studio for MySQL.

Comment: Many Thanks for the adv, but I've found there are some free software for data comparison.